# How to know how many custom notifications have been sent in one Apex Transaction (Apex Test)

Tags: apex, governorlimits

Currently I'm building a feature that use the `Messaging.CustomNotification` Apex class, and I'm building the corresponding test methods, but I haven't found a way to check that the notification has been sent. I was thinking use the `Limit` class, but I haven't found any method that works for what I need.

Is there a way to check that in an Apex Test?

Answer (score 1):

No.. this seems to be one of the scenarios where asserts are not possible

The way notifications work -> fire and forget.

Normally in these scenarios if the try doesn't fail we assume its a  success

```
try {
    notification.send(addressee);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.debug('Problem sending notification: ' + e.getMessage());
}
```

there are some limits though

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.process_limits_customnotification.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

In situations like these, put your custom notification send  logic into a separate class - e.g. `MyCustomNotificationSender`.

Then, at test time, construct a mock version of the `MyCustomNotificationSender` called `MockCustomNotificationSender` with the same signature as your `MyCustomNotificationSender` methods.

The mock simply counts how many times it is called in a static variable (or, if using `ApexMocks`, it will count for you)

Then, inject the mock into the runtime version of the code-under-test. Finally, execute the code-under-test.

Your mock can also throw exceptions as part of dependency-injected constructor parameters.

You don't really need to know if the `send` method works as SFDC will take care of that - you should be more interested in whether you tried to send the notification and how many times

For another take on custom notifications, see the [andyinthecloud blog](https://andyinthecloud.com/2019/06/30/getting-your-users-attention-with-custom-notifications/)